# NetBeans: Unable to Create CUnit Tests - Grayed Out Menu Options

Tags: c, netbeans, cunit

I use NetBeans since version 7.4 (currently using v21) to develop several C projects (libraries and programs) in Linux distributions (mainly Ubuntu and recently Archlinux). For completeness, I use GNU autotools.
I'd like to use the CUnit integration in NetBeans to create test units. The problem is that when I try to create a test right-clicking on the file, the relevant commands in the pop-up menu are always grayed-out [pop-up menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPOBV.png). I've never been able to use this functionality in NetBeans.

I followed the [tutorial](https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/kb/docs/cnd/c-unit-test/) in the official page.
I verified that CUnit is correctly installed. For some of my project CUnit is already used (there are working tests implemented).
I checked if there are some project configuration parameters related but I have found none.